# Java Socket specify a certain network interface for outgoing connections

Tags: java, sockets

OK. I know similar questions were asked before, but this is different.

I noticed from responses to similar questions that I can use `Socket.bind` to specify a certain network interface for outgoing connections. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html) page is an official instruction on that.

Now, my machine has two NICs `eth0` and `eth1`, and the system routing table sets `eth0` as the outgoing interface for connecting to a server `S`.

Then I tried the following:

```
Socket so = new Socket();
so.bind(new InetSocketAddress("ip.address.of.eth1", 0));
so.connect(new InetSocketAddress("ip.address.of.S", 80));
```

I used WireShark to capture the packets, and noticed that the "Source Address" field of IP header was indeed `ip.address.of.eth1`. But by checking Ethernet headers, I noticed that the source MAC address is actually the MAC address of `eth0`, that is, the packets were actually still sent out via `eth0`!

Could anyone help explain why it had this behavior? Is it expected? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the result of the 'weak end system model'. It's too broad to describe here but it is discussed in [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Considering the spec of weak end system model "A host MUST NOT restrict itself to sending (non-source-routed) IP datagrams only through the physical interface that corresponds to the IP source address of the datagrams", I guess there is no way to do it in Java then, right?

Comment: The *host* 'MUST NOT' do it at all. Nothing to do with Java whatsoever.